# What to call this type of temporary arrangement on the road?

Tags: single-word-requests

When I walked on the road, I happened to pass a pool of mud. Somebody had already set some blocks of stones and bricks on the mud from one end to other end in order to pass it. I could pass it by treading on the blocks of stones. What do you call such a temporary arrangement to walk on?

Comment: I’d say that they were “stepping stones”   but stepping stones can be permanent or temporary.

Comment: @Jim: Please consider posting this as an answer. Such an arrangement is indeed a sequence of *stepping stones*.

Comment: I’m getting on a plane.  An answer will have to wait until I land.

Answer (score 4):

The structure you are looking for are called [*stepping stones*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepping_stones). The name is applicable to any walkway of that type, whether temporary or permanent.

Answer (score 2):

It's **"an improvisation"** or **an improvised solution**

> - [**Improvisation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improvisation) is the process of devising a solution to a requirement by making-do, despite absence of resources that might be expected to produce a solution.
> - [**Improvised**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/improvised) (adj) done or made using whatever is available.

an [**improvised bridge**](http://schoolsforsalone.org/gallery/tree-of-hope), for example

[image]

Comment: Despite the fact that that the "improvised bridge" depicted is probably many thousands of miles away from me, perhaps with an ocean or two in between, I am still incredibly uncomfortable with it existing.  Well done.

Answer (score 2):

An **impromptu walkway** might work.

> Impromptu: Prompted by the occasion rather than being planned in advance

(AHD)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may refer to it as a  ***temporary/emergency [walkway](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280534/what-to-call-this-type-of-temporary-arrangement-on-the-road):***

> - a passage or path for walking.

( AHD)

> - or an *emergency stone path*.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for the adjective *ad hoc*:

> - [**Ad hoc**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ad-hoc) concerned or dealing with a specific subject, purpose, or end.

Unfortunately the difficulty index is a bit high for this word :/

> I crossed the ad hoc walkway today

Answer (score 1):

**makeshift walkway,** or simply **makeshift,** is what I would call such an arrangement.

> **MAKESHIFT**
>
> *noun*
>
> 1. a temporary expedient or substitute:  *We used boxes as a makeshift
>      while the kitchen chairs were being painted*.
>
> *adjective*
>
> 2. Also, makeshifty. serving as, or of the nature of, a makeshift.

[**Random House Dictionary**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/makeshift)

Alternately, consider **jury-rigged walkway**.

> **JURY-RIGGED**
>
> : done or made using whatever is available; "*crossed the
>   river on improvised bridges*"; "*the survivors used jury-rigged fishing
>   gear*"; "*the rock served as a makeshift hammer*"

[**Princeton University, Farlex Inc**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jury-rigged)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specifically refer to a road, it's a **rudimentary workaround**.

> "rudimentary" definition: basic, simple, not elaborated; of a
>   primitive kind; very imperfectly developed.
>
> "workaround" definition: a plan, method or process of dealing with a
>   problem without eliminating it (often used in computer science).